# Squares in a field with $q^n$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a ﬁeld with $q^n$ elements, where $q$ is an odd prime. Write $q^n=2m +1$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}.$

If $r \in F^{\times},$ show that the equation $y^2= r$ has a solution iff $r^m=1.$

Comment: Have you covered the result of the multiplicative group of a finite field being cyclic? What do you know about subgroups of finite cyclic groups?

Comment: To add to Jyrki's comment, here's a hint: $F$ finite field $\implies F^\times$ is cyclic.

Comment: As you are new user here are a few friendly pointers from your friendly moderator: I'm afraid your question looks suspiciously like a copy/pasted homework. Asking help for homework is largely ok, but does press peoples buttons. If you want to avoid negative attention, then you should include your own thoughts and attempts. For otherwise it is difficult to give you helpful pieces of advice. An answerer who does not know what you know is very much in the dark. They may guess and post a full solution. But your teacher may not like it if it uses material you have not covered yet :-)

Comment: And, I will edit the title. This one is pretty bad. There is no such thing as *a cyclic field*. It does suggest that the answer to my first question is affirmative :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen We have covered the result you mention, and the fundamental theorem of finite cyclic groups.

Comment: Ok. So what do you know about the squares in a cyclic group of odd order?

Comment: All those elements are perfect squares, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The non-zero elements of $\mathbf F_{q^n}$ are a cyclic group of order $q^n-1=2m$. So, if $y^2=r$, we have $r^m=y^{2m}=1$.

Conversely, suppose $ r^m=1$, and let $\zeta$ be a generator of $\mathbf F_{q^n}^{\times}$. We can write $r=\zeta^k$  for some $k$. Since a generator has order $2m$, the hypothesis implies:
$$\zeta^{km}=1\iff km\equiv 0\mod 2m \iff k\equiv 0\mod 2,$$
so that $k=2l$ for some $l \enspace (0\le l<m).\,$Then $$r=(\zeta^l)^2.$$